# Will Today word change the sentence tense?

Tags: past-tense, simple-past

According to book I ma using, the author introduced the difference between past and simple as following:
[image]

My question is: if I didn't change today to yesterday will it makes difference?

**I was in class today.**

---

Please I am learning English. If you encounter any mistake help me to correct it :)

Comment: If you are speaking  _after_ classes have finished for the day, you might say 'I was in class today'.

Comment: @KateBunting so, it depends upon context rather than how it's written ?

Comment: The book is over-simplifying to a ridiculous degree. _Yesterday_ is incompatible with present time (in ordinary contexts), but any of the other combination can happen.

Answer (score 1):

'Today' is quite a long time in some contexts so present, future, past simple and past perfect tenses can all be combined with the word "today" For example:

If you are speaking during a break in your class you can say "I am in class today".

If you're speaking before your class begins, you can say "I will be in class today".

If you're speaking when you are no longer in class you can say "I was in class today"

If you went to the bowling alley between the end of class and when you were speaking you could also say "I had been in class today before I went to the bowling alley." (although this is much less common).

There are some other valid uses of some of these tenses combined with the word 'today' but I believe that listing them would make this answer too complex.

The examples you have been given are just to make the difference between the present and past tenses clear. They don't mean that 'today' can only be used with the present tense.

Answer (score 0):

If you are speaking after the end of the class but it's still the same day then it's okay to use 'I was in class today', so it's still past tense because the action of 'being in class' was in the past. But if you attending the class at that moment then it's not okay to use was. So in the end it depends on context.